# Unable to load autopath rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading my app from rails 3 to rails 4.
I've the below line in my application.rb file

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I am keep getting this error for several  models. Please help me to fix this.

Error:

```
 LoadError - Unable to autoload constant Issue, expected /home/user/optimus/app/models/issue.rb to define it
```

issue.rb  # First 3 lines

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redmine::SafeAttributes
  include Redmine::Utils::DateCalculation
```

Comment: Once I faced the same issue, You can try this `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`.

Comment: Is there a model/class named `Issue`? Where is it defined?

Comment: there some naming convention problem with `issue` model, I think?

Comment: Sontya. I added that line too. Still the same issue.

Comment: Shivam, yes there is a model issue which in app/models/issue.rb file

Comment: can you post 'Issue' model, first 2 lines, class definition ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: Sontya! 

I added the first 3 lines in my post. Please take a look!

Comment: that's look good, try this `config.autoload_paths += [config.root.join('app')]`

Answer (score 0):

check the **whitespacing** while saving the model names...such as

`app/models/issue.rb` -**desired**

`app/models/issue.rb<whitespace exists>`-**Need to delete this whitespace**